# Complicated Regex Capturing - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to capture the part below

```
a1A ^(?\..*+) and a1A ^(?\..*+) g:a1A ^(?\..*+)
```

However I can't create a 100% working regex for what I am trying to achieve.

The regex must capture anything after the letters followed by a colon in the beginning also the letters before the colon and then it must capture after the first matching of letters followed by a colon and also the letters before the colon till space. e.g. for this line below:

```
x:a1A ^(?\..*+) z:a1A ^(?\..*+) g:a1A ^(?\..*+)

--> captured value must be 'x', 'a1A ^(?\..*+)', 'z', and 'a1A ^(?\..*+) g:a1A ^(?\..*+)'
```

another example

```
x23:a1A ^(?\..*+) z:a1A ^(?\..*+) g:a1A ^(?\..*+)

--> captured value must be 'x23', 'a1A ^(?\..*+)', 'z' and 'a1A ^(?\..*+) g:a1A ^(?\..*+)'
```

and then in case there is no string starting with any letter and followed by a colon, then it must capture anything till the space followed by a letter or letters and a colon. e.g.

```
a1A ^(?\..*+) s:a1A ^(?\..*+)

--> captured value must be 'a1A ^(?\..*+)', 's' and 'a1A ^(?\..*+)
```

Comment: Did you intentionally not split the `g:a1A` part in the first two examples?  It partially appears in the third example too which is why it seems like it might be a typo.  I am going to post an answer assuming you meant the last captured groups for the first two examples to be `'a1A ^(?\..*+)' 'g' and  'a1A ^(?\..*+)'`.

Comment: @machee Yes, sorry I edited my question and fixed the last example, it has to capture third letter:anychar pattern in first 2 examples, only first 2 letter:anychar patterns are seperators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex I came up with is `?:([^: ]+):)?([^ ]+ [^ ]+)(?: |$)`.

```
(?:([^: ]+):)?  // don't capture the colon, capture the part before the colon
([^ ]+ [^ ]+)   // capture the two groups that may or may not be preceded by the colon
(?: |$)         // end at either a space or the end of the line/string
```

Here is a fiddle where I tested it out: http://jsfiddle.net/9nbsu84v/